# History of the Telegraph Equation

Tags: physics, math-history

I find myself studying partial differential equations but in my book only the mathematical form of the telegraph equation and its solution is expressed, could someone tell me the story about where it was the first time it appreciated?

Comment: Chapter 3, "Heaviside the Telegrapher", in [The Maxwellians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Maxwellians) by B.J.Hunt details the history of the telegraph equations as they were developed by Heaviside.

Comment: Does the first paragraph at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations help? (It was the top entry when I googled on "telegraph equation.")